# Install Laravel on easyPHP install Windows 7 - Bizarre install results

Tags: php, windows-7, laravel-4, wamp, easyphp

I installed easyphp on my windows laptop, then cmd'd the composer install, and then used composer to install Laravel. Here are my issues and was wondering if you would be able to help me sort through them:

1. My easyphp local install shows up on my web browser, but my laravel install does not.
2. The files are definitely not in the same place as what many other laravel users show in their installs.
3. Runnng through the sample laravel routing/view example doesn't result in anything - nothing works.
4. I can't seem to find anything that explains what's going on here.

I'm not looking for opinions on which is better than what (i.e. wamp, xamp, etc.) - I just want to get up and running.

Screenshots:
[image: Laravel install location vs easyphp install location]
[image: Where's Laravel on LocalHost?]
[image: Funny SublimeText folder structure]

Help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Had the same experience and a lot of other negative experience with easyPHP, they admitted that easyPHP installs it self with lot of errors, my offer for you would be Bitnami Wamp Stack, has way much more fetures than easyPHP, and Laravel loves it https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp

Comment: Yep, I gave up on it and just installed a fresh wampserver with composer and laravel. It seems to be working as expected. I just can't customize the localhost domain, but I'm guessing that has to do with a firewall at work?

Thus, I have to type http://localhost:81/laravel-master/public/ everytime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using easyphp, you need to enable mod_rewrite. It will be a simple thing to do and you then need to add RewriteBase / in your .htaccess file.

However, just use xampp and you will get it running without any problems.

Comment: I gave up on easyphp. I installed wampserver and originally set it up and had it working fine with http://localhost/laravel-master/public.

However, now, it only works when I type http://localhost:81. it can't read the index.php in the public directory anymore and I never edited that file. Is there something I'm missing when starting up (I see wampserver is online)?